# Pass MSSQL table values to javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a website with asp.net mvc 4 & EF6 where I want to pass values from MSSQL table to javascript. So far everything is working fine except if I pass `Latitude` & `Longitude` values for `google-map-api` function, map doesn't show up in my view. I used `Html.HiddenFor` helper to pass the value from `<span>`. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult BranchDetails(int BrId)
    {
        Branch branchDetails = abdb.Branches.Find(BrId);
        return View(branchDetails);
    }
```

**View**

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var marker;
        var LatTag = document.getElementById("Lat");
        var Lat = LatTag.getElementsByTagName("span");
        var LngTag = document.getElementById("Lng");
        var Lng = LngTag.getElementsByTagName("span");
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(LatTag, LngTag),
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<body>
    <div class="container well" style="min-width: 100%; padding-right: 5px;">        
        <div id="googleMap"></div>
        <span id="Lat">@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Latitude)</span>
        <span id="Lng">@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Longitude)</span>
        <h4><b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</b></h4>
        <p><strong>Address:</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)</p>
        <p><strong>Contact No. :</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactNo)</p>
        <p><strong>Contact Person(s):</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactPerson)</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Point to be noted that my `Longitude` & `Latitude` fields in MSSQL are set in `varchar` mode. I'm not sure if its causing the problem but just felt needed to inform. How can I solve this problem? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found my own solution. This worked for me, instead of giving span id, I gave `Html.HiddenFor` helper the id. For some reason javascript was not picking the id of the span I guess. Here are my codes,

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var marker;
        var Lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Lat").value);
        var Lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Lng").value);
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng),
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body>
    <div id="googleMap"></div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Latitude, new { id = "Lat" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Longitude, new { id = "Lng" })
</body>
```